# Association definition in UML specification

Tags: uml

An association defines a `semantic relationship` between classifiers. The instances of an association are a `set of tuples relating instances of the classifiers`. Each`tuple value may appear at most once`. The Association represents a `set of connections` among instances of the Classifiers. An instance of an Association is a Link, which is a`tuple of Instances` drawn from the corresponding Classifiers

I wonder if there is someone helps me understand every word of the association definition especially the highlighted ones?because I read about it from different resources but all of them say the same words but I would like a more elaborated definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> semantic relationship

This means there's a structural relationship between the things being associated that arises from the problem space.  For example: the association `Person owns Dog`.  In a dog licensing application, this relationship is the central concept; the application exists to manage the links between people and dogs.  It's a 'semantic' relationship because it has meaning which originates from the problem space.

> set of tuples relating instances of the classifiers

A tuple is 'an ordered set of elements' ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple)). An example of the Dog-Ownership association could be `("Fido", "Fred")` where "Fido" represents a Dog and "Fred" a Person.  An association can be  represented as a set of tuples in that there is one tuple for each combination of Dog & Person for which the relation holds; e.g.

`[("Fido", "Fred"), ("Angel", "Chuck Norris"), ("Boatswain", "Lord Byron")]`

Note there are no tuples for pairs where the relationship *doesn't* hold; e.g. `("Fido", "Lord Byron")`.

> each tuple value may appear at most once

It's not possible for the set to contain duplicates as this would just be saying the same thing twice.  So there's no point adding `("Fido", "Fred")` again to the list above; we already know Fred owns Fido.

> The Association represents a set of connections among instances of the Classifiers

This is just another way to think about the relationship.  For each tuple in the set, you can think of a link - or connection - between the related objects.

> An instance of an Association is a Link, which is a tuple of Instances

See above.  Each tuple represents one linked pair of objects.  Links are to Associations as Objects are to Classes.  Classes have many objects; Associations have many Links.

Fundamentally associations exist to show where things are systematically linked to other things.  Tuples and sets are a way to think about and/or represent those linked things.  (In fact I'd quibble somewhat with the definition in your OP: the links in an association *can be represented as* as a set of tuples: but that's not what they *are*, it's how they're modelled.  The same information could equally be modelled by a Graph, where each object was represented by a vertex (node) and each association an edge.

hth.

**EDIT:**

Responding to your questions.  Looks like you understand it pretty well; some observations.

First, here's how I would model it:

[image]

Now to each of your points:

> Name: is the name of Association relationship(optional,you can give it a name or not)

I prefer verb phrase based naming as it brings out the meaning of the relationship.  My model can be read directly as:

- Each Person owns many Dogs (where 'many' means 0 or more)
- Each Dog is owned by exactly one Person

Doing so removes the need to name the association explicitly, although you can still do so if you want.

> visibility(I am not care about it,at least for now, I didn't realize its importance until now).

I would agree.  Personally, I never annotate models with visibility.

> Name:(here is the name of MemberEnd ),so,I left its default name in the screenshot

See comment about association naming above.  I prefer verb-based naming to role-based: 'owns' is much more explicit in describing the purpose of a relationship than naming the association end 'dog' or 'dogs'.

> the owner of memberEnd [...]

Personally: I don't use this.  There's a whole other discussion about this that tbh I don't believe has a material impact in most cases.

> Navigable [...]

Again I don't use this personally.  In reality navigability should be derived from the underlying behaviour.  Does it require navigating one way/both? Then set navigability accordingly.  However some people like to specify it explicitly, on basis it makes the implementation clearer (If only navigable one way it can be implemented with reference(s) in one class only; if bi-directional it needs references in both directions - with attendant logic to keep things consistent).

> Multiplicity

I agree with your selection.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi@sfinnie!I am fortunate enough to get such answer .I’ve spent the past 3 hours 

or so just absorbing every single word ,I really can't thank you 

enough. 
I have modelled the association `Person owns Dog` . I hope you 

comment on my try,confirm if what I am trying to do is correct and 

valid in UML.

this a class diagram: http://postimg.org/image/cjn6js2ex/    this is the corresponding `properties view` of the association 

relationship in class diagram (to edit its properties)
http://postimg.org/image/llblttv5d/

Comment: Here is my understanding about association relationship:
#Name: is the name of Association relationship(optional,you can give 
it a name or not)
#visibility(I am not care about it,at least for now, I didn't realize its 

importance until now).#Name:(here is the name of MemberEnd ),so,I left its default name in 

the screenshot which is the instance of class type,but in our example 

it was Fido

Comment: #the owner of memberEnd:I have two options either association or 

classifier[As I understood ,I should specify a classifier for both ends 

because I think  Fido is of type `Dog class` and Fred is of type `Person 

class`]but I don't know in Which cases AssociationEnds should be 

owned by association ,not owned by classifier?

Comment: #Navigable :it works according to the previous property,owner.
this means, if the owner set to association, then the navigable will 

automatically set to false
if the owner set to classifier, then the navigable will set to True.
(but I don't know Why Owner and Navigable work together?)
#Aggregation:I have three options :none,shared,composite[none has 

been selected because it is neither aggregation,whole-part 

relationship nor composition,stronger than the aggregation]

Comment: #Multiplicity[1..* has been attached to the near end of Fido,the 

number of  dogs participate in the relationship, 1 has been attached 

to the near end 
of Fred,the number of person participate in the relationship]

Comment: @Carlos, see expanded answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and kind help @sfinnie !       #As far as I know,when you associate two or more classes it is done 

thanks to two `UML Properties`. These latter are the `ends` of your 

association and are `instance` i.e. they are typed by their classes. So, 
an association is created between two classes on a class diagram but 

between each class and association you have a `UML properties`.right?
#so, `owns` and `owned by` are `UML properties`?Are they instances 

of Dog and Person respectively(owns is an instance of Dog,owned by is an 

instance of Person)?

Comment: Hi @sfinnie ! You probably helped more than you think you did. Thank you.It took a lot of effort to get these straight in my own head.